# user cannot edit the page

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I have given the marketing role the 'create new', 'edit own' and 'delete own' permission for the Article content type however when I log in with that account the 'edit' button doesn't appear on the article page so that user cannot modify the page[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjpOI.png)

[image]

Comment: In the screenshot you have edit own content checked, but edit any content is not. So is the marketing user the creator of the article?

Comment: I have unchecked 'edit any' because if another member of staff (also from the marketing role) logs in they can delete content that their colleagues posted! (content that isn't their own!) Is what I have done correct?

Comment: @testin1 that is correct, but what I am really asking is, did you make sure that the marketing user authored the article? check the author info for that article. If they are not the author, then they cannot edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code may be it helpful

```
if ($query == $user->uid && arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && arg(2)== 'edit' ){

$query_path= db_query("select n.nid from {node} n
where n.nid =$nid")->FetchField();
 drupal_goto('node/'.$query_path);
}
```

place uid with your role id

Answer (score 0):

While the query you posted is vague, you can follow few below checks to debug more on this issue:-
a.) Check if the logged in user has the role(Marketing) which you allowed to edit the content.

b.) Check if the node you want to edit actually belongs to that specific user.

c.) Try to access the url /node/[content-node-id]/edit manually and see if you are able to access the page. If so is the case then Check if your theme is supressing the tabs by any chance. Try by changing the theme to a different one and look for tabs.

Hope this helps :)